# My Shimano EZ fire plus on the right side isn't shifting below 3 and the left one wont shift above 3

Tags: shimano, chain, shifter

The shifters have been doing this since I got the bike a while ago, but the chain is also starting to fall of the gears when I'm riding it. I don't know how to fix this so can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

At first I suspected a twist/grip shift, but no these are integrated flatbar brakes and shifters.

[image]

So you have two problems, which may be related.   Shifting with shifter, and the chain not staying in gear.

Start by cleaning the bike - some shifting problems are related to dirt in the derailleurs or compressed into the cassette.

Then try to push the rear derailleur around by hand - it should move toward the wheel under hand pressure and return outward under spring pressure.

It can help to get the rear wheel off the ground.  Try hanging the bike so the rear wheel can turn but the bike is not going to fall over.  A workstand helps but you can use ropes to a tree branch or whatever is available.

Then stand beside bike and turn the right pedal with your left hand.  Use your right hand to actuate the shifter.  Does the shifter go through all 6+ clicks?   Can you make the rear derailleur move through its whole range by pulling on the exposed inner cable while slow-pedalling ?

That the chain comes off suggests the indexing isn't quite on the right spot, but getting the shifters and derailleurs working better would help a lot first.

As for the front derailleur - it is a simpler system overall, but should be easier to comprehend.  Same diagnosis techniques.

Do be mindful of the rear wheel spinning here - it can all be fairly good at eating fingers and hair etc.

Comment: About the chain, I meant that it comes off all the way down past the smallest gear, and I was wondering if I needed to tighten it.

Comment: @EliGeesaman Start by making sure the derailleurs move smoothly and easily across the whole range of motion, then re-index the gears.  You shouldn't need to touch the two limit screws on each derailleur unless someone's already fiddled them.